# Determinar movimientos por posición de una matriz

Tags: java

Es un juego que estoy desarrollando y tengo que tener estructura de datos ya sean nodos o tipos colas para poder definir mi juego.El código descrito, tiene el fin de que si se encuentra `X` en alguna posición me de movimientos diferentes para poder seguir con el juego.Es algo fiable o tendría que mejor crear nodos para así poder definir una solución, es posible saber si una matriz `string` es igual a otra?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Taken {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Bienvenido al juego \n Las reglas son:");
        System.out.println("La x en cada posición que se encuentre puede efectuar dos movimientos");

        String nodoraiz[][] = new String[2][2];     
        introducirArray(nodoraiz);

        for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
                System.out.print ("["+nodoraiz[m][n]+" "+"]");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
        validaposi(nodoraiz);
    }

    private static void introducirArray(String[][] a) {
        Scanner insertar = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
                System.out.print("Inserte Valor: ");
                a[i][j] = insertar.next();
            }
        }       
    } 

    private static void validaposi(String[][] b){
        if (b[1][1] == "x") {
            System.out.print("Derecha 1");
            System.out.print("Abajo 2");
            Scanner vali = new Scanner(System.in);
        }
        else if (b[1][2]=="x"){
            System.out.print("Izquierda 1");
            System.out.print("Abajo 2");
            Scanner vali = new Scanner(System.in);
        }
        else if (b[2][1]=="x"){
            System.out.print("Derecha 1");
            System.out.print("Arriba 2");
            Scanner vali = new Scanner(System.in); 
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Izquierda 1");
            System.out.print("Arriba 2");
            Scanner vali = new Scanner(System.in); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No me queda claro cual es tu problema. ¿Quieres saber si dos matrices de `string` son iguales?

Comment: @Capt.Teach En el método validaposi quiero que si la x este en cierto lugar me diga que puedo hacer movimientos   Hacia arriba o abajo, pero esa parte me da error y no me toma en cuenta las condiciones ni me imprime nada más allá de que me imprima la matriz string que ingrese

Comment: Para comparar  `string` debes utilizar [equals()](http://www.w3api.com/wiki/Java:String.equals())

Comment: @MarioGuiber gracias!, existe algún hilo donde pueda ver estructuras tipo arboles, soy un noob en la programación

Comment: @Clippo Aqui encontrarás todo tipo de estructuras: http://www.ciberaula.com/articulo/arboles

Comment: @MarioGuiber sabes al igual poner .equals(“x”) me dio error

Comment: Que error te aparece ?

Comment: @MarioGuiber ArrayIndexOutBoundsException en la línea 44

Comment: Ah claro por que los indices de tu `array` no son los correctos. Reduce 1 indice en todos, por ejemplo `b[2][1]` quedaría así `b[1][0]`. Ese error da cuando excedes el tamaño de tu `array`